# how to print order id & all other detail customer detail for event observer sales_order_save_commit_after

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, event-observer, configuration

How to print order id & all other order detail. For event observer "sales_order_save_commit_after" ?

Currently using these codes for get all order detail for event observer "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"

```
$orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');            
    Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getData('customer_id'));
    $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
    $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds);
```

singleton
                    Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer
                    smsntf_cancel_order

```
public function smsntf_cancel_order($observer){
// how to print order id & all other detail customer detail, sales detail of order.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in `Observer.php` file

```
public function smsntf_cancel_order($observer)
{
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      echo $order->getId();

      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
      echo "<pre>"; print_r($customer->getData());    
}
```

Comment: after get once order id . i can get another detail same as using in checkout_onepage_controller_success_action?

Comment: yes : $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      echo $order->getId();